# validate textbox entry 3 digit numbers separated by commas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox on a registration forms that collects telephone area codes - my smart self didn't think my customers would be so great to enter 5 digit zip codes instead of 3 digit area codes, so now I need to make a make a jquery or javascript function to validate the entry is in ###,###,###,###,###... format there is no limit to the number of area codes they can enter.
problem is I have no idea how the code should go - any ideas
my text box

```
<input type="text" id="acode" name="acode" />
```

I appreciate it

***Completed code***

HTML

```
  <label for="acode">Enter area codes separated by commas (757,804,252,###):</label>
  <input type="text" id="acode" name="acode" onblur="valarea(this.form)"/>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function valarea(form)
{
inputvalue =form.acode.value;
var regexp = /^\d{3}(?:,\d{3})*$/;
if (inputvalue != "")
{
if (regexp.test(inputvalue)) {
//nothing happens
} else {
alert('You have entered an invalid value, you should have listed 3 digit telephone area codes for the areas you are interested in shopping separated by commas (757,804,252,###) Please Correct the problem before continuing')
form.acode.focus()
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
var regexp = /^\d{3}(?:,\d{3})*$/;
if (regexp.test(inputvalue)) {
  // Valid, do something with it...
} else {
  // Invalid, show error.
}
```

For more information on regular expressions in Javascript, [see the MDN page for regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need it, but if you want to validate a list of current area codes, I could send you a list. I work for [GreatData.com](http://www.GreatData.com) and we maintain current area codes for the U.S. and Canada. Just go to the site for the contact info and ask for a file.

Don't know your exact application, but you could possibly have a picklist where they can pick the appropriate area codes and build the comma delimited list yourself.